# My AHK script to run and send keystrokes to one program isn't working for another program

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to sign onto my VPN with a hotkey, which means running the program, tabbing through the fields (all of them auto-populated), and pressing "Enter" once you've tabbed onto the "Submit" field.

I couldn't get it working at first (I'm very new to AHK) so I started testing it out on Notepad as I found it easier to see where things were going wrong that way. Anyway, I ended up with the following script, which works perfectly:

```
#!n::
Run Notepad.exe
WinActivate Untitled - Notepad
WinWaitActive Untitled - Notepad
Send {Tab 8}
Send {Enter}
return
```

But it's not working for my VPN. I have managed to get it working for the VPN by splitting it across two stanzas like this:

```
#!f::
Run [file address omitted]
return

#!o::
WinActivate [window title omitted]
WinWaitActive [window title omitted]
Send {Tab 8}
Send {Enter}
return
```

I'd really rather have it all encompassed in a single hotkey, though. Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the problem may be that your VPN takes longer to start up than Notepad, so when you get to the `WinActivate`, the VPN still hasn't started, so it does nothing, and thus your program hangs on the `WinWaitActive`.  You could use a [`WinWait`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm) before the `WinActivate` to prevent this behavior.  Also, from the [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm), the `WinWaitActive` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you so much! WinWait made it work. I tried removing WinWaitActive though and it broke, so I guess it is necessary sometimes!? Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Charlie Armstrong for the answer! The final working code:

```
#!f::
Run [file address]
WinActivate [window title]
WinWait [window title]
WinWaitActive [window title]
Send {Tab 8}
Send {Enter}
return
```